# Check if Contains in Array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I wanted to hide menus conditionally based on `userAccess`. My problem is if has many roles.
How will I be able to do it?

Pls check my code below

**MENU**

```
export default [

      {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Leaders',
        url: `/leaders`,
        userAccess: true,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: 'Things',
        url: `/things`,
        userAccess: 'Super Admin',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        text: 'Users',
        url: `/users`,
        userAccess: 'Admin',
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        text: 'Products',
        url: `/products`,
        userAccess: ['Admin', 'Manager'],
      },
    ];
```

**CODE**

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const checkAccess = (access, role) => {
  if (typeof access === 'string') {
    return role === access;
  };
  return access;
};

const Menu = ({ items, isCollapseMenu }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const role = useSelector((state) => state.role);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      {items.map(
        (item) =>
          checkAccess(item.userAccess, role) && (
            <MenuItem
              key={item.id}
              title={item.title}
              icon={item.icon}
              text={item.text}
              shortText={item.shortText}
              url={item.url}
              submenu={item.submenu}
              isCollapseMenu={isCollapseMenu}
            />
          )
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Why not filter first before mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `includes` method to check access and also try to filter array before doing map like below:-

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const checkAccess = (access, role) => {
  if (typeof access === 'string') {
    return role === access;
  };
  if(Array.isArray(access)){
   return access.includes(role);
 }

 return access;
};

const Menu = ({ items, isCollapseMenu }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const role = useSelector((state) => state.role);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      {items.filter(itemToFilter => checkAccess(itemToFilter.userAccess, role)).map(
        (item) => (
            <MenuItem
              key={item.id}
              title={item.title}
              icon={item.icon}
              text={item.text}
              shortText={item.shortText}
              url={item.url}
              submenu={item.submenu}
              isCollapseMenu={isCollapseMenu}
            />
          )
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-write checkAccess function as follows
and make sure your roles are always in an array either it contains single value or multiple values

```
const checkAccess = (access, role) => {
  if (typeof access === 'string') {
    return role.indexOf(access) > -1;
  };
  return access;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle 3 conditions,

1. String.
2. Array
3. boolean

   ```
   const checkAccess = (access, role) => {
    if (typeof access === 'string') { // String check
       return role === access;
    };

    if(Array.isArray(access)){ //Array check
      return access.includes(role);
    }

    return access; // Boolean check
   };
   ```